# How to extract xml from a segment text using javascript?

Tags: javascript, xml

How to extract xml from a segment text using javascript?

I have a segment text:

```
hello world <a><b>value</b></a> some demo
```

I want to extract the xml in the text using javascript:

```
 <a><b>value</b></a>
```

Is there any js library to do this?

Comment: That's valid html, so you can just do it with normal DOM parsing like `aElement.outerHTML`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend [JKL ParseXML](http://www.kawa.net/works/js/jkl/parsexml-e.html) it's lightweight and is built for this purpose.